# Enabling Customer 360 Privacy Center / GDPR not visible

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, configuration, gdpr

Working on the following module based on GDPR module https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_c360_privacy_rtbf.htm&type=5&release=232 (Delete Customer Data with Right to Be Forgotten Policies) but unable to find the Customer 360 Privacy Center in my org to configure the functionality.

Is there any app or enablement need to be done for configuring?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_privacy_center.htm&type=5&release=228)

> Customer 360 Privacy Center is available as an add-on subscription.

The provisioning is handled by your Salesforce Account Executive and Product manager. Please get in touch with them.

Once enabled, you should be able to open Customer 360 Privacy Center from the App Launcher.